# Why has my app been rejected by the Apple app store?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to publish an app made in flutter that uses the "in_app_purchase" library to purchase subscriptions.
Everything works fine but they still giving me the same errors.

---

### Issues for rejection

Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed

We're looking forward to completing our review of your app, but we need more information to continue. Specifically, we noticed that your binary includes the PassKit framework for implementing Apple Pay, but we were unable to verify any integration of Apple Pay within your app.

Next Steps

If your app integrates Apple Pay, please indicate where in your app we can find Apple Pay functionality.

If your app does not include any Apple Pay functionality, please indicate this information in the Review Notes section for each version of your app in App Store Connect when submitting for review.

Resources

Learn more about implementing Apple Pay.

Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions

We noticed that your app did not meet all the terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement.

We were unable to find the following required information in your app's binary:

– A functional link to the Terms of Use (EULA)
– A functional link to the privacy policy

We were unable to find the following required item(s) in your app's metadata:

– A functional link to the Terms of Use (EULA)
– A functional link to the privacy policy

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please add this missing information. If the above information is present, please reply to this message in App Store Connect to provide details on where to locate it.

I add access links that open a standard Apple EULA license page.
Also link to the privacy policies of the app.
But they keep giving me the same errors.

[Subscription screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnDnk.png)

Could you help me solve these problems?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about an application store's policy, which is not on-topic for Stack Overflow. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/11107541) for more information.